# CiviMail - 'No recipients': nothing added to table civicrm_mailing_recipients

Tags: civimail, groups

I have migrated an existing installation to a new server followed by an upgrade to 4.7.31.

When creating a new mailing I keep getting "No recipients" **when I add groups or smartgroups**.
If I add recipients of past *mailings*, it works as expected (I get xx recipients).

In the database
- the table civicrm_mailing_group gets a new record (so OK)
- the table **civicrm_mailing_recipients** does not get new records added.

So the problem seems to be related to populating the civicrm_mailing_recipients table. How do I debug/solve this?

Comment: You could start by clearing out templates_c folder, clear caches and also rerun the Smart Group cache link from Manage Groups ie /civicrm/group?reset=1&update_smart_groups=1

Comment: I tried clearing all kinds of caches and rerunning the Smart Group caching several times but to no avail.

I ended up redoing the entire migration and upgrade, and the problem no longer occurs now.
So it's fixed for me, but I have no idea what setting, add-on or cache was responsible.

Comment: Hmm. well you might as well Answer your own Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried clearing all kinds of caches and rerunning the Smart Group caching several times but to no avail.

I ended up redoing the entire migration and upgrade, and the problem no longer occurs now.

So it's fixed for me, but I have no idea what setting, add-on or cache was responsible.

**EDIT**: an issue has been opened for this:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21856

Comment: his seems to be an issue with multilingual installations. The issue can be replicated by adding another language and then turning on Multiple Languages Support. After this the problem appears and disappears again when Multiple Languages Support is switched off. 4.7.27 was working, not sure whether the problem first appeared with 4.7.28, 4.7.29 or 4.7.30. Which version were you coming from?